# Debugger break location with F# exception handling

Tags: f#

I came across this recently and wanted to check if there was something I was misunderstanding about F# exceptions. I am using Visual Studio 2012. Given the following F# code:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    try
        raise (System.AccessViolationException("foo"))
        printfn "Should not get here"
        raise (System.AccessViolationException("foo"))
        printfn "Should not get here either"
    with | :? System.FormatException -> printfn "Should not get here"
```

This will raise and AccessViolationException which should not be caught by the `with` statement because the `with` only handles System.FormatException. I expected the debugger to be at the first `raise` when the exception occurs, but it is actually at the end of the `with`:

[image: debugger]

Now the problem is I can't see where the exception was raised from, also I can't see any information about the exception such as stacktrace. I don't think that I want to change the exception settings for individual exceptions because I would want to know the location of any unhandled exception (similar to `C#` or `VB.NET`) not when thrown.

If this is just the way that it is, then that is OK, but I just wanted to ask since I am not very familiar with `F#` and I wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing something. I had a look online and did not find anything about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to modify your exception settings to break when that exception type is thrown (or a category of exceptions in the exception settings) then you need to make sure that your code takes care of unhandled exceptions however is most appropriate for your code.

```
try
    raise (System.AccessViolationException("foo"))        
with 
    | :? System.FormatException -> printfn "Should not get here"
    | _ as ex ->             
#if DEBUG
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
#else
        printfn "Unhandled exception ('%s'): '%s'" (ex.GetType().Name) ex.Message
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. Yes, I agree that you normally want to handle the generic Exception, but there are cases where it is useful (e.g. when debugging) to allow the exception to propagate through so that the debugger breaks at the location of the throw. It is then possible to see the values of the local variables, etc. I am more wondering if this is by design or if I was missing something as it is different from the way C# and VB work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible without explicitly enabling Break On Throw for that exception in the exception settings. The documentation for the Exception Assistant specifies that it's available for VB.Net and C#, so I would assume that it's just a happy coincidence that it also happens to work decently with F# and shouldn't be assumed to have supported equivalent functionality.

Comment: OK. I don't want to break on throw for an exception, but rather break on throw for unhandled exceptions. I think it is just the way that it works in F#, which I am fine with, was just making sure I wasn't missing anything.